# What should be the format of sender's phone number to be passed to SMS User Consent API?

Tags: android, phone-number, sms-retriever-api

As per the docs:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/request

we can specify a sender phone number from which we know the SMS message will originate. But it isn't mentioned which phone number format to be followed.

How should country could be included?
Any example of phone number formats the API will respect would be very helpful.

Comment: it should be +countrycodephonenumber